# Convert function to another type (function casting) in Go

Tags: function, types, go, type-conversion

I've recently learnt that in the `net/http` package, there's a pattern of usage that keeps confusing me most. It is function type conversion. It is like this:

```
(function a) ->convert to-> (type t)
(type t) ->implentments-> (interface i)
```

So, if there's a function that takes interface `i` as its parameter, it will invoke the function a, this is the way `net/http` implements it.

But when I write my own code, I've had many misunderstandings on this pattern. My code goes like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type eat interface {
    eat()
}
type aaa func()

func (op *aaa) eat() {//pointer receiver not right
    fmt.Println("dog eat feels good")
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
func dog() {
    fmt.Println("I'm a dog")
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////

func feelsGood(a eat) {
    a.eat()
}

func main() {
    b := aaa(dog)
    feelsGood(b)
}

//error:aaa does not implement eat (eat method has pointer receiver)
```

Type aaa has method eat, the same function name and parameter signature, which conforms to the rule of interface eat, but why does it give that error? Does the receiver matter?

Another question is with only a function and type, excluding an interface, the code goes like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type aaa func()

func (op *aaa) eat() {
    op()
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
func dog() {
    fmt.Println("I'm a dog")
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////

func main() {
    obj:=aaa(dog)
    obj.eat()
}
//error:cannot call non-function op (type *aaa)
```

First, is `op` an anonymous function, regardless of the error?

Second, it works well after I remove the asterisk, but why? `op` is instance of type `aaa`, receiver is `op`, does `op` stand for function dog()? The http package uses `f(w,r)` the same way, but it is a little bit of hard to understand. Is `op` a type, or an instance, or an anonymous function?

It seems like my comprehension of function converting is not right, but I've also checked many posts on Google, and none of them can teach me how to think of it and use it correctly.Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

**Question 1:**

In Go, for a type T (like aaa in your case), `T` and `*T` have different method sets.

So, a value of type T can only access method:

```
func(t T)Foo() { ... }
```

While a value of type *T can access both methods:

```
func(t T)Foo() { ... }
func(t *T)Bar() { ... }
```

In your case, you have two options. Either you declare the `eat` method for `aaa` instead od `*aaa`:

```
func (op aaa) eat() {
    op()
}
```

Or you pass the pointer to `b` to `feelsGood`:

```
feelsGood(&b)
```

**Question 2:**

Yes, this question is related to the first. But in this case you can access the method because `obj.eat()` will be short for `(&obj).eat()`.

Your problem here is that you cannot call a function on the function pointer (op *aaa). Your options are to either create the method for `aaa` instead of `*aaa`:

```
func (op aaa) eat() {
    op()
}
```

Or to call the `op` function on the value and not the pointer:

```
func (op *aaa) eat() {
    (*op)()
}
```

Comment: But,I've only declared T type,*T type doesn't even exist,then,how could a non-exist *T type implements an interface?And more,even if *T type exists,what is the difference between T and *T,the only one I could think of is *T is pointer to T,a pointer's method vs a normal method,what does that mean?Thinks!

Comment: I've read other posts on when should use T function and when should use *T function,they all tell me that if you want to modify the receiver itself then you should use *T,otherwise you should use T,but on this case,how would I use the aforementioned considerations to explain whether T or *T method should be used?

Comment: @user3505400: `*T` is implicitly declared as the pointer to `T` when `T` is declared, so it does exist. And yes, the difference is mainly whether you can modify the receiver or not. So why doesn't Go just take the pointer to the value in the Interface? It is because (afaIk) when you pass a value to a function, `a := struct{42}; Foo(a)`, you should be able to rest assure that `a` will not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question: See http://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets which exmplains everything better than I could. You may even search stackoverflow and the golang-nuts mailing list for this question as this comes up very often.

The second is just the same IMHO: `aaa` doesn't have an `eat`-method (only `*aaa` has).